# configuration of in-line references for IEEE conference paper

Tags: citing, ieee-style

I'm trying to use the following references for an IEEE conference publication, originally I wrote the paper using a different style, and it seems they're incompatible.

I've tried to include the code that follows at the end of my file, just before `\end{document}`, but finally they are all rendering as `[?]` when using the command `\cite{this guy}'.

How can I structure these properly to appear in an IEEE conference format?

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[\protect\citename{Abad et al.}2014]{Azad}
Abad, Azad, and Alessandro Moschitti.
\newblock 2014.
\newblock {\em "Creating a standard for evaluating Distant Supervision for Relation Extraction."}.
\newblock {\em Italian Conference on Computational Linguistics CLiC-it.},
1.

\bibitem[\protect\citename{Intxaurrondo et al.}2013]{Intxaurrondo}
Intxaurrondo, Ander, Mihai Surdeanu, Oier Lopez de Lacalle, and Eneko Agirre.
\newblock 2013.
\newblock {\em "Removing noisy mentions for distant supervision."}.
\newblock {\em Procesamiento del lenguaje natural 51.},
41-48.

\bibitem[\protect\citename{Hoffmann et al.}2011]{Hoffmann}
Hoffmann, Raphael, Congle Zhang, Xiao Ling, Luke Zettlemoyer, and Daniel S. Weld.
\newblock 2011.
\newblock {\em "Knowledge-based weak supervision for information extraction of overlapping relations."}.
\newblock Association for Computational Linguistics.
\newblock {\em In Proceedings of the 49th Annual Meeting of the Association for Computational Linguistics: Human Language Technologies-Volume 1.}
541-550.

\bibitem[\protect\citename{Manning et al.}2014]{Manning}
Manning, Christopher D. and  Surdeanu, Mihai  and  Bauer, John  and  Finkel, Jenny  and  Bethard, Steven J. and  McClosky, David.
\newblock 2014.
\newblock {\em "The Stanford CoreNLP Natural Language Processing Toolkit."}.
\newblock http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P/P14/P14-5010
\newblock Proceedings of 52nd Annual Meeting of the Association for Computational Linguistics: System Demonstrations.
55--60.

\bibitem[\protect\citename{Marcus}1993]{Gusfield:97}
Marcus, Mitchell P., Mary Ann Marcinkiewicz, and Beatrice Santorini.
\newblock 1993.
\newblock {\em "Building a large annotated corpus of English: The Penn Treebank."}.
\newblock Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, UK.
\newblock {\em Computational linguistics 19.2},
313-330.

\bibitem[\protect\citename{Mintz et al.}2009]{Mintz}
Mintz, Mike, Steven Bills, Rion Snow, and Dan Jurafsky.
\newblock 2009.
\newblock {\em "Distant supervision for relation extraction without labeled data."}.
\newblock Association for Computational Linguistics.
\newblock {\em In Proceedings of the Joint Conference of the $47^{th}$ Annual Meeting of the ACL and the $4^{th}$ International Joint Conference on Natural Language Processing of the AFNLP.}
Volume 2.

\bibitem[\protect\citename{Riedel et al.}2010]{riedel2010modeling}
Riedel, Sebastian, Limin Yao, and Andrew McCallum.
\newblock 2010.
\newblock {\em "Modeling relations and their mentions without labeled text."}.
\newblock Springer Berlin Heidelberg.
\newblock {\em Machine Learning and Knowledge Discovery in Databases.},
148-163.

\bibitem[\protect\citename{Riedel et al.}2013]{13}
Riedel, Sebastian, Limin Yao, Andrew McCallum, and Benjamin M. Marlin.
\newblock 2013.
\newblock {\em "In NAACL-HLT."}.
\newblock Linguistic Data Consortium, Philadelphia.
74–84.

\bibitem[\protect\citename{Sandhaus}2008]{Sandhaus}
Sandhaus, Evan.
\newblock 2008.
\newblock {\em "The New York Times Annotated Corpus."}.
\newblock Linguistic Data Consortium, Philadelphia.

\bibitem[\protect\citename{Schoenmackers et al.}2010]{Schoenmackers}
Schoenmackers, Stefan, Oren Etzioni, Daniel S. Weld, and Jesse Davis.
\newblock 2012.
\newblock {\em "Learning first-order horn clauses from web text."}.
\newblock Association for Computational Linguistics.
\newblock {\em In Proceedings of the 2010 Conference on Empirical Methods in Natural Language Processing.}
1088-1098.

\bibitem[\protect\citename{Surdeanu et al.}2012]{Surdeanu}
Surdeanu, Mihai, Julie Tibshirani, Ramesh Nallapati, and Christopher D. Manning.
\newblock 2012.
\newblock {\em "Multi-instance multi-label learning for relation extraction."}.
\newblock Association for Computational Linguistics.
\newblock {\em In Proceedings of the 2012 Joint Conference on Empirical Methods in Natural Language Processing and Computational Natural Language Learning.}
455-465.

\bibitem[\protect\citename{Vrandečić and Krötzsch}2014]{Markus}
Vrandečić, Denny, and Markus Krötzsch.
\newblock 2014.
\newblock {\em "Wikidata: A Free Collaborative Knowledgebase".}.
\newblock Communications of the ACM 57, no. 10.
78-85.

\bibitem[\protect\citename{Vrandečić and Krötzsch}2014]{Markus2}
Erxleben, Fredo, Michael Günther, Markus Krötzsch, Julian Mendez, and Denny Vrandečić.
\newblock 2014.
\newblock {\em "Introducing Wikidata to the Linked Data Web."}.
\newblock Springer International Publishing
\newblock In The Semantic Web–ISWC 2014.
50-65.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I write:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,cite}
\usepackage{epstopdf,epsfig,mathtools,caption,subcaption,amsfonts}
% And all the packages you need...
```

After the article and, at the and:

```
% ---------------------------------------------------------
\bibliographystyle{bib/IEEEbib}
\bibliography{bib/bib}

\end{document}
```

If you do not have the IEEE package look here: http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html. Download the files in a folder and modify them with your article and citations.

Comment: `epsfig`? Really?

Comment: It is a question that I always had, maybe it's redundant, or I do a mistake.  But with `epsfig` MiKTeX does its work.

Comment: `epsfig` exists just for back compatibility of older documents. It should never be used in a new one.